# Enable copy out of NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, xamarin

I have some text in an NSOutlineView that I would like to copy out when the user highlights and presses Cmd-C, or uses the Edit Menu. However, in the Edit Menu, copy is always grayed out. What steps do I need to do in the OutlineViewDelegate or elsewhere in order to enable this?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have some specific text to copy? and is Multiple selection allowed?

Comment: absolutely, but i would need to massage the data going into nspasteboard

Answer (score 0):

You change the binding for Copy in MainMenu.xib and bind it against a user-defined method.
Using treecontroller IBOutlet you can get the selected objects and do whatever you want to.

Here is sample app for you:
https://github.com/aneesh171/OutlineViewSampleApp.git